# CakePHP paginator case sensitive

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, pagination

When trying to sort data using the CakePHP Paginator, it is returning case-sensitive sort results. I have tried adding UPPER around the field I specify in the order query, but that doesn't seem to be working. I'm using CakePHP 2.0.3 with a PostgreSQL database. My $paginate variable and the code to call it are:

```
var $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 25,
    'order' => array(
        'User.first_name' => 'asc'
    )
);
..

(In my view function)
    $users = $this->paginate('User');
```

How can I force CakePHP to return a case-insensitive sort result?

Comment: why is the data case sensitive in the first place? shouldnt `utf8_unicode_ci` (CI stands for case insensitive) solve the issue at its source instead of trying to fix the symptoms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a shame that you can't use something like this:

```
 'UPPER(User.first_name)' => 'ASC'
```

Which would be fairly basic.

I had this issue in a project, whereby I replaced the 'order' array with something like this:

```
'order' = "UPPER(first_name) ASC"
```

which successfully gave me the correct output.

Unfortunately, however, clicking the column header fields to sort my paginated table then replicated the issue, whereby my names were once again case-sensitive.

The solution that I came up with was to modify the PaginatorComponent of cakephp itself, so that my sort order would always be correct.

In the PaginatorComponent (/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php) I modified the validateSort function, replacing the following line:

```
$options['order'] = $order;
```

With the four lines below:

```
foreach($order as $order_field=>$order_direction){
    $neworder['UPPER('.$order_field.')'] = $order_direction;
}
$options['order'] = $neworder;
```

It's not elegant, and is essentially just forcing the 'UPPER()' around the field name.

This worked in my particular situation whereby I need to always have case-insensitive queries.

Comment: I don't like to mess with the cake core when I can help it, but this is a pretty simple solution that shouldn't have any impact on other areas as it's only used for paginating, which should be case insensitive anyway. Seems to be working with this change, thanks!

Comment: It is worth noting that this will only work for alphanumeric fields, where the UPPER() function actually works.
I ran into an issue with this were I attempted to sort by a datetime field, and it failed [ERROR:  function upper(timestamp without time zone) does not exist].
As a workaround, and once more, it's hacky, for my specific application, I wrapped the 'four lines' above, with
if ($options['sort'] != "User.created") { //four lines }
This allowed my users to sort by the created columnm without the code dying - for any other fields, you'd need to throw them in the above if.